# multidimensional arrays excel

Tags: arrays, excel, multidimensional-array

Hi I have a loop that works, but it takes hours to run due to the size of the data. I am trying to use an array, which I have never used before. Based on all of the tutorial information I have looked through I think my array is correct, but it is not giving me any output. Can someone help me understand why? Below is the code that works and my array that does not:

```
    'this works (but will take hours)
    'For j = 5 To lcwr
    '    For m = 2 To lrwr
    '        For n = 2 To last_row
    '            If wr.Cells(1, j) = ex.Cells(n, 5) Then
    '                If wr.Cells(m, 2) = ex.Cells(n, 2) Then
    '                    If wr.Cells(m, 1) = ex.Cells(n, 1) Then
    '                        wr.Cells(m, j).Value = ex.Cells(n, 6)
    '                    End If
    '                End If
    '            End If
    '        Next n
    '    Next m
    'Next j
    Dim array1() As String

    last_row = ex.Range("A" & ex.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lrwr = wr.Range("A" & wr.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lcwr = wr.Cells(1, wr.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ReDim array1(last_row - 2, 3)

    For i = 0 To last_row - 2
        array1(i, 0) = ex.Range("A" & i + 2)
        array1(i, 1) = ex.Range("B" & i + 2)
        array1(i, 2) = ex.Range("E" & i + 2)
        array1(i, 3) = ex.Range("F" & i + 2)
    Next

    For j = 1 To lrwr
        If wr.Cells(1, 5) = ex.Cells(j, 5) And array1(j, 0) = 
        ex.Cells (j,1) And array1(j, 1) = ex.Cells(j, 2) Then
        wr.Cells(j + 1, 5).Value = array1(j, 2)
        End If
    Next
```

EDIT: I am trying to convert a report that gives me a group of stores, UPCs, shipment wave date, and wave percentage from duplicating stores and UPCs by having the wave dates across the top with the percentages underneath. Ex.

```
Input:
Location    UPC    Wave Date        Wave Percentage
Store 1     UPC1    Date1           50
Store 1     UPC1    Date2           50
Store 2     UPC1    Date1           100
Store 3     UPC1    Date1           100
Store 4     UPC2    Date1           25
Store 4     UPC2    Date3           75
Store 5     UPC2    Date3           100
Store 6     UPC2    Date3           100
Store 7     UPC3    Date2           50
Store 7     UPC3    Date4           50

Desired output:
Location    UPC    Date1    Date2   Date3   Date4
Store 1     UPC1    50      50      
Store 2     UPC1    100         
Store 3     UPC1    100         
Store 4     UPC2    25              75  
Store 5     UPC2                    100 
Store 6     UPC2                    100 
Store 7     UPC3            50              50
```

I've done all the formatting to get the dates to go across the top and remove the duplicate store/UPC combinations.

For each date column in the output table, I need the macro to look at the Location and UPC on the output page match that with the Location, UPC, and wave date on the input page and return the wave percentage value.

Each input I generate will contain a different number of rows, dates, and percentages.

Comment: Where isn't it giving you output? Is it correctly populating the array in your `for i = 0 to last_row - 2` loop? Also, perhaps an array is overkill for what you're trying to do. Can you describe a little why you're setting it up like this (this will hopefully prevent any [XY problems.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).).

Comment: It may be easier if you posted an example of the two worksheets and how it is supposed to look.  It is a little hard to follow the if statement.

Comment: Can you post a little more on the variable names too? That'd help because as @Scott points out, it's a little convoluted.  That's also why I ask to describe the logic too, as there may be a better way to get your data set up than that loop.

Comment: @BruceWayne- Thanks for looking at this. I have edited the post to provide more input. Hopefully this helps. If there is anything else that will help clarify please let me know. If there is a better way to do what I'm attempting I'm all for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will be any faster but it does it without all the loops and if statements.

```
Sub AB()

Dim ex As Worksheet
Dim wr As Worksheet
Dim wrLastRow As Long
Dim exLastRow As Long
Dim wrLastColumn As Long
Dim rng As Range

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ex = Sheets("Sheet20") 'Change to your Original Sheet
Set wr = Sheets("Sheet21") 'Change to your target sheet
exLastRow = ex.Cells(ex.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

wr.Range("A1:C" & exLastRow).Value = ex.Range("A1:C" & exLastRow).Value
wrLastRow = wr.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
With wr.Range(wr.Cells(1, 1), wr.Cells(wrLastRow, 2))
    .RemoveDuplicates Array(1, 2), xlYes
    .Sort wr.Range("A1"), xlAscending, wr.Range("B1"), , xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End With

wr.Range("C1").Clear

With wr.Range(wr.Cells(2, 3), wr.Cells(wrLastRow, 3))
    .RemoveDuplicates 1, xlNo
    .Sort wr.Range("C2"), xlAscending, Header:=xlYNo
End With

wr.Range("C2", wr.Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Copy
wr.Range("C1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
wr.Range("C2", wr.Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Clear

wrLastColumn = wr.Range("C1").End(xlToRight).Column
wrLastRow = wr.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

wr.Cells(2, 3).FormulaArray = _
    "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet20!R2C4:R11C4,MATCH(Sheet21!RC1&""|""&Sheet21!RC2&""|""&Sheet21!R1C,Sheet20!R2C1:R11C1&""|""&Sheet20!R2C2:R11C2&""|""&Sheet20!R2C3:R11C3,0)),"""")"

wr.Range(wr.Cells(2, 3), wr.Cells(wrLastRow, 3)).FillDown
wr.Range(wr.Cells(2, 3), wr.Cells(wrLastRow, wrLastColumn)).FillRight

wr.Calculate
With wr.Range(wr.Cells(2, 3), wr.Cells(wrLastRow, wrLastColumn))
    .Value = .Value
End With

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked. It got it down from 12 hours to 2 hours. Ultimately though it is quicker to manually do what I need from a pivot table.

Comment: @ABlack Then you need to mark Ron's question as correct.

Answer (score 0):

A Pivot Table will come pretty close to what you want.
Drag:

- Location to Row Labels
- UPC to Row Labels
- Wave Date to Column Labels
- Wave Percentage to Values
- Set report format to `Tablular Form`

Turn off the subtotals and totals.
Add some formatting and change some labels

[image]

Comment: You are right. As much as I wanted to be able to click a button a everything go, this way ended up being the quickest and most efficient. Thanks.

Comment: @ABlack you can still click on a button. Just record macro for the steps to set up a pivot table. Then edit the code - probably all you'll need to do is something to reflect the proper range to make into a table - something like .Current region might work. And attach this to a button.